Why is the value for sem_open(O_CREAT) ignored if the semaphore already exists?
According to the manual, sem_open(name, O_CREAT, mode, 1) returns success (the semaphore address) if the semaphore exists. But the caller can't know whether:

the newly created semaphore is now at 1
the existing semaphore was at 0 and is still at 0, or
the existing semaphore was at 1 and is still at 1, etc

Would calling sem_open(name, O_CREAT, mode, 0) followed by a separate sem_post() be one correct fix for this ?

What is there to fix? The function returns a sem_t, but does not automatically lock it for you. Unlocking it would be an error, as your code does not hold a lock on the semaphore at that point in time.

Existing code I'm trying to fix incorrectly assumes the sem didn't exist and assumes it owns the resource after sem_open(O_CREAT, 1). But if it did exist and was locked, it will get unlocked elsewhere while this O_CREAT, 1 call assumes it still owns it.

That's simply what the call does.  You're telling the system "If the semaphore exists, open it and disregard the initial value argument; if not, create it with the given initial value".  So you should only use this call if you don't need to know which of the two took place.
If you do need to know, then you need to write different code.  AFAIK there isn't a single call for "either open existing semaphore or create new one, and tell me which was which", but you can do the two separately.  Using sem_open without O_CREAT will open the semaphore if it exists, and fail if it does not.  Using O_CREAT | O_EXCL will create the semaphore (with the given initial value) if it does not exist, and fail if it does.
Thus you could do
sem_t *s;
if ((s = sem_open("foo", 0)) != SEM_FAILED) {
    // opened existing semaphore
    // you can use sem_getvalue() to determine its current value
} else if (errno == ENOENT && (s = sem_open("foo", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, perms, 42) != SEM_FAILED) {
    // created brand-new semaphore with initial value 42
} else {
    // something wrong, handle error
}

There is the possibility for a race if another process created the semaphore in between your two calls to sem_open.  In that case, the second call will set errno = EEXIST and you could loop and retry.
I didn't understand your comment about sem_post; it's unclear when that would be useful.

When the available resource count increases by one, I can do s=sem_open(O_CREAT, 0); sem_post(s) to increase the value by 1 regardless if it's the first resource (sem didn't exist) or not (sem existed).

What happens is clearly stated in the manual:

If
O_CREAT is specified, and a semaphore with the given name already
exists, then mode and value are ignored.

So:

if it does not exist at the call it is created and initialised at 1;
if it exists, its value is not determined by the call.

IMHO: if you are asking such a question, probably you are going to misuse semaphores. Semaphores are used to "communicate" in between processes. Roughly, if you need to use the resource denoted by a semaphore just wait on it, if you relinquish the use do a post. So if you "open" an existing semaphore, its value should not matter, try what you have to do. If you need a new one, use O_EXCL to ensure that it does not exist (in the case if open failure that means that something is wrong in the environment: semaphore name conflict in between set of processes, shutdown of processes fails to delete the semaphore, etc).

"So if you "open" an existing semaphore, its value should not matter" -- this is what I changed the code to do, as described in the question: I changed sem_open(name, O_CREAT, mode, 1) to sem_open(name, O_CREAT, mode, 0) + sem_post(). Which should IMO resolve the semaphore misuse.
